# Is there a way to read the form data of an incoming request inside a CustomProtocolMapper [Keycloak SPI]

Tags: java, keycloak, openid-connect

I am trying to implement Keycloak as an IAM, the Problem that I have is, that I need to authenticate the user (already working) but also authorize him. The authorization should be accomplished through keycloak directly, but the security information (like roles, etc.) is available over an REST interface externally.
The way it is working now goes as followed:

- authentication request (default)
- "authorization" request → keycloak server (with extra form param)
- keycloak server → CustomProtocolMapper (calls external REST interface and adds claims to Token)
- Token → frontend client

This worked until I used a refresh token to refresh the ID Token. The Cookie that is used to authenticate the user is not sent to the keycloak server, because of security reasons (Cookie labeled as "Secure" but connection over HTTP). To fix this I upgrade my keycloak server to use HTTPS/TLS and now i am getting errors because the "HttpRequest" is no longer available. Any ideas on how to get the Request Body of an HTTPS Request inside a CustomProtocolMapper? I know that the Authenticator Providers has access to it, but i dont know/ didnt find anyway to add claims to the Token inside it.

```
@Override
    protected void setClaim(IDToken token, ProtocolMapperModel mappingModel, UserSessionModel userSession, KeycloakSession keycloakSession,
            ClientSessionContext clientContext) {
        String contextParamName = mappingModel.getConfig().get(CONTEXT_PARAMETER);
        // worked with http
        HttpRequest request = keycloakSession.getContext().getContextObject(HttpRequest.class);
        String contextId = request.getFormParameters().getFirst("activeContext");

        LOGGER.warn("activeContext: " + contextId);
    }
```

Thanks in advance,
best regards